# How many different totals can be obtained in a test with $20$ questions if one can obtain $-1$, $0$, or $4$ for a question?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

In an exam there are $20$ questions, one can obtain either $-1,0$ or $4$ in each question based on marking scheme. How many different totals can he obtained in the test?

One thing I observed different that even without repetition there is repetition as different permutation can obtain same number.

I tried several ways like beggar method and others, but tackled the same above problem.

But one thing I deduced that the lowest he can get is -20 and highest he can get is $80$.

So total $101$ number but in this some numbers are there he can't obtain so answer must lie between $1-101$

But certainly unable to find the answer.

Comment: We for any $-20\le k \le 0$ we can get but geting $k$ negative ones and $20-k$ 0s.  And $0 \le 4m \le 4\times 20$ we can get by getting $m$ fours and $20-m$ zeros.  For any $4m-1$ we can get by getting $m$ fours and $1$ negative one and the rest zeros *ASSUMING* $m \le 19$.  So $79=4\cdot 20-1$ is not possible.  For any $4m-2$ assuming $m\le 18$ we can get by $m$ fours and $2$ neg ones and the rest zeros and if $m\le 17$ we can get $4m-3$ similaraly.  So we can get all scores except $79,78,77,74,73$ and $69$. We have to show those are impossible but that's not hard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use the fact that one can obtain $0$ marks from a question to our advantage. Let me explain.

As you have rightly concluded, the total has to fall in the range $-20$ to $80$.

Now, you can obtain every total from $0$ to $-20$. For example, $-3$ can be obtained by getting $-1$ each from three questions and $0$ from the rest.

Also, as long as you have three questions free to use, you can obtain the numbers between two multiples of $4$. For example, $41 = 11 \times 4 + (-1) \times 3$. Now, $20 - 3 = 17$. So, you can obtain every total upto $17 \times 4 = 68$.

Thereafter, we need to be a little cautious. If you get $4$ for eighteen questions, your total would be $72$, $71$, or $70$, depending on what you get for the other two questions. So, $69$ is ruled out.

Similarly, if you get $4$ for nineteen questions, you will end up with $76$ or $75$ marks. So $73$ and $74$ are ruled out.

And then, if you get $4$ for all twenty questions, you will get a total of $80$. So $77$, $78$, and $79$ must be ruled out.

Putting it all together, the totals impossible to get are - $69$, $73$, $74$, $77$, $78$, and $79$. So $6$ totals out of $101$. Meaning, one can obtain $95$ different totals.